# Foxpro: Check whether table exists via vfpoledb

Tags: sql, oledb, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I access data in .dbf files via `System.Data.OleDb` (vfpoledb.dll). How can I find out whether table exists via SQL command? Something similar to the following on SQL server:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    --Do Stuff
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dbc file you can query it to see if the table exists.

```
string dbc = "northwind.dbc";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE ALLTRIM(ObjectType) = 'Table' AND UPPER(ALLTRIM(ObjectName)) = '{1}'", dbc, tableName.ToUpper());
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    bool tableExists = dt != null && dt.Rows.Count == 1;
}
```

But really you don't need a sql command or a dbc file to get that information.  You can get it straight from the OleDbConnection using the GetSchema method.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    DataTable tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
    conn.Close();

    var tableExists = (from row in tables.AsEnumerable()
                        where row.Field<string>("Table_Name").Equals(tableName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                        select row.Field<string>("Table_Name")).FirstOrDefault() != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint about GetSchema().

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you are connecting to DBF tables that are "FREE" tables and NOT actually part of a connected "database" (.dbc), then you can just check for the file's existence or not... Such as in C# via

```
if( File.Exists( PathToTheDatabaseDirectory + TableYouExpect + ".DBF" ))
   file is there
else
   file is missing
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it only using SQL but maybe you could check for the existence of the file on disk using the [File.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) or you could write some code to check for the existence of the dbf using the OleDb classes:

```
private bool DbfExists(string dbfName, string connectionString)
{
    bool dbfExists = true;

    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", dbfName);

        using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                dbfExists = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                reader = null;
            }
        }
    }

    return dbfExists;
}
```

I have not tried compiling this code so it may need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Thnaks. I do something similar now but I wonder whether there is a SQL command for it.